# Unable to delete Windows System Image

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, backup, windows-backup

I'm on Windows 8 Pro (64bit) and I'm trying to configure an Image Backup using the strangely named "Windows 7 File Recovery" tool.

To start with, I want to delete any existing system images from my external HD, which has a capacity of 1.82TB. However, somehow I'm unable to delete all system images:

- The HD has a capacity of 1.82TB
- of which the property page of the drive reports 1.38TB as used and 445GB free
- when I display hidden and protected files, and select everything on that drive, the total size on disk is reported as 1.15TB.

So where are the missing 235GB (1.38TB - 1.15TB)?

The "Manage Windows Backup Space" control panel seems to provide a hint, since it reports a system file (size 263GB), which more or less matches the missing space. But I'm unable to find it, and the control panel won't let me delete anything (the button "Change Settings..." next to "System image" used to be enabled, and I've deleted any other image that were present, but now it seems to consider that no images are left to delete).

How can I reclaim that space?

[image: "Manage Windows Backup Space" control panel]

Comment: I would use windirstat.info to figure out what is using your storage space.

Comment: As you are not system Administrator you cannot view used space in system folders. Try to run for example notepad as Administrator, open dialog to open file and through that file dialog try to show space occupied by all files on that external disk, it shoud show all of it.

Comment: @Ramhound: Did so - it only reports 1.15TB used.

Comment: @week: Nope, still reports only 1.15TB when selecting all files; and 1.38TB when right-clicking on the drive.

Comment: Are you sure you are using UAC Admin?

Comment: @week: yes. I'm getting the UAC prompt.

Comment: Perform a disk cleanup on the drive in question, I bet a bunch of that space is stuff marked for deletion.

Comment: @Brutick: Disk cleanup didn't help. But defragmenting the drive did - it freed up the missing space, and now the backup control panel reports '0 bytes' for system image. Weird.